# How to update filter weights in CNN?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, matlab, conv-neural-network

I am trying to build a Convolutional Neural Network (CNN) from scratch to learn its basics. However, I haven't found any information about *how* the weights from the kernels get updated in each iteration using backpropagation.

The only explanation I found on the internet was [this one](https://www.quora.com/Where-can-I-find-a-detailed-description-of-weights-update-in-convolutional-neural-networks) but I'm not sure if that is right or if I didn't implement it correctly in MATLAB.

I'm using ["same" convolution](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/conv2.html#inputarg_shape) and $3\times3\times1$ kernels. As far as I understand, all the positions of the kernels appear at all the locations of the images. So, according to the explanation above, I should sum all the contributions for each "appearance" and use *that* as the update of each value of the kernel.

I tried to implement this but I eventually end up with all NaNs all over the network, so something is diverging. I believe the problem is in this line:

```
kernel{1} = kernel{1} + sum(sum(0.01*eta * delta_conv{1} .* x_out_conv{1}));
kernel{2} = kernel{2} + sum(sum(0.01*eta * delta_conv{2} .* x_out_conv{2}));
```

where `kernel` is a cell-array containing the two kernels (one for each convolution layer), `eta` is the learning rate, `delta_conv` is the gradient coming from the output of that layer and `x_out_conv` is the current output for each neuron in the layer.

That is constantly adding values, and it eventually goes out of control. Is that the way to update the weights of the kernels in a CNN?

**EDIT**:

To clarify, I'm using the convention from Hertz, Krogh & Palmer's *Introduction to the Theory pf Neural Computation*. When I talk about 'deltas', I'm referring to:

[image]

where $w$ are the weights, $E$ is the error function, $\eta$ the learning rate, $\zeta$ the desired outputs, $O$ the actual output, $g()$ the activation function, $\xi$ the inputs of the network and $h$ the linear output such that $g(h) = V$, the output of each neuron.

The rule to update the weights then becomes:

[image]

Comment: Hey.. I want to ask did you find the  solution? I am facing the exact same problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of two things is probably going wrong. Either your learning rate is too high, or your gradient computation is incorrect. (Or both)

If it is your learning rate, simply reduce it by a few orders of magnitude and that should fix it.

In order to establish whether your gradient computations are correct or not, use the method of finite differences:

Pick one image or input, and start all the weights of your network at some deterministic value (0 perhaps). Then compute the loss, which is a single scalar value. Then pick one of your kernels, and increment one of the entries by a small epsilon (1E-6) perhaps. Compute the loss again. The derivative of the loss with respect to the weight is simply $\frac{\delta loss}{\epsilon}$. Now repeat this for all the weights in that one kernel. Check that it is equal to delta_conv.

Another possible problem might be weight initialization. Starting all the weights at 0, although not ideal, may help you determine if initialization is the culprit.

Finally, I recommend only using a single layer network while debugging, if you are not doing that already. Once that is working, you can add in more layers of your network and see if keeps working.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. There is something I don't understand. `delta_conv` is $256\times256$ (the size of the output of that layer) while the kernels are $3\times3$. So what are you referring to when you say that I should check if "it is equal to `data_conv`" ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean when you said delta_conv is the gradient coming from the output of the layer. What do you mean mathematically? At some point, you must have computed $\frac{\partial \text{loss}}{\partial \text{kernel_weights}}$. That's what you want to compare with the finite differences method.

Comment: I'm following the convention in Hertz, Krogh & Palmer's *Introduction to the Theory of Neural Computation*. If you don't have access to it, let me know so I can edit my question so that it is more understandable (I thought it was standard nomenclature, but what I named $\delta$ is not $\frac{\partial E}{\partial w_k}$).

Comment: Yes, please do edit the question to specify what $\delta$ is

Comment: Done, I've added some definitions.

Comment: I see. I think in this case, the best approach is to compute $\Delta w_{pq}$ with $\eta = 1$ and check that it is equivalent to $-\frac{\partial loss}{\partial w_{pq}}$

Answer (score 0):

Concerning NaNs, you should also watch out for [exploding gradients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vanishing_gradient_problem) by simply clipping the computed gradient values to a maximum / minimum threshold.